# How to transform input data into following format? - groupby

Tags: scala, functional-programming

What I have is the following input data for a function in a piece of scala code I'm writing:

```scala
List(
  (1,SubScriptionState(CNN,ONLINE,Seq(12))), 
  (1,SubScriptionState(SKY,ONLINE,Seq(12))), 
  (1,SubScriptionState(FOX,ONLINE,Seq(12))), 
  (2,SubScriptionState(CNN,ONLINE,Seq(12))), 
  (2,SubScriptionState(SKY,ONLINE,Seq(12))), 
  (2,SubScriptionState(FOX,ONLINE,Seq(12))), 
  (2,SubScriptionState(CNN,OFFLINE,Seq(13))), 
  (2,SubScriptionState(SKY,ONLINE,Seq(13))), 
  (2,SubScriptionState(FOX,ONLINE,Seq(13))), 
  (3,SubScriptionState(CNN,OFFLINE,Seq(13))), 
  (3,SubScriptionState(SKY,ONLINE,Seq(13))), 
  (3,SubScriptionState(FOX,ONLINE,Seq(13)))
)
```

`SubscriptionState` is just a case class here:

```scala
case class SubscriptionState(channel: Channel, state: ChannelState, subIds: Seq[Long])
```

I want to transform it into this:

```scala
Map(
  1 -> Map(
        SubScriptionState(SKY,ONLINE,Seq(12)) -> 1, 
        SubScriptionState(CNN,ONLINE,Seq(12)) -> 1, 
        SubScriptionState(FOX,ONLINE,Seq(12)) -> 1),

  2 -> Map(
        SubScriptionState(SKY,ONLINE,Seq(12,13)) -> 2, 
        SubScriptionState(CNN,ONLINE,Seq(12)) -> 1, 
        SubScriptionState(FOX,ONLINE,Seq(12,13)) -> 2, 
        SubScriptionState(CNN,OFFLINE,Seq(13)) -> 1),  

  3 -> Map(
        SubScriptionState(SKY,ONLINE,Seq(13)) -> 1, 
        SubScriptionState(FOX,ONLINE,Seq(13)) -> 1, 
        SubScriptionState(CNN,OFFLINE,Seq(13)) -> 1)
)
```

How would I go about doing this in scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my approach to the problem. I think it may not be a perfect solution, but it works as you would expect.

```
  val result: Map[Int, Map[SubscriptionState, Int]] = list
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .view
    .mapValues { statesById =>
      statesById
        .groupBy { case (_, subscriptionState) => (subscriptionState.channel, subscriptionState.state) }
        .map { case (_, groupedStatesById) =>
          val subscriptionState = groupedStatesById.head._2 // groupedStatesById should contain at least one element
          val allSubIds = groupedStatesById.flatMap(_._2.subIds)
          val updatedSubscriptionState = subscriptionState.copy(subIds = allSubIds)
          updatedSubscriptionState -> allSubIds.size
        }
    }.toMap
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a "simple" solution using `groupMap` and `groupMapReduce`

```
list
  .groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
  .view
  .mapValues{ 
    _.groupMapReduce(ss => (ss.channel, ss.state))(_.subIds)(_ ++ _)
     .map{case (k,v) => SubScriptionState(k._1, k._2, v) -> v.length}
  }
  .toMap
```

The `groupMap` converts the data to a `Map[Int, List[SubScriptionState]]` and the `mapValues` converts each `List` to the appropriate `Map`. (The `view` and `toMap` wrappers make `mapValues` more efficient and safe.)

The `groupMapReduce` converts the `List[SubScriptionState]` into a `Map[(Channel, ChannelState), List[SubId]]`.

The `map` on this inner `Map` juggles these values around to make `Map[SubScriptionState, Int]` as required.

I'm not clear what the purpose of inner `Map` is. The value is the length of the `subIds` field so it could be obtained directly from the key rather than needing to look it up in the `Map`

Answer (score 1):

An attempt using `foldLeft`:

```
list.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, Map[SubscriptionState, Int]]) { (acc, next) =>
  val subMap = acc.getOrElse(next._1, Map.empty[SubscriptionState, Int])
  val channelSub = subMap.find { case (sub, _) => sub.channel == next._2.channel && sub.state == next._2.state }
  acc + (next._1 -> channelSub.fold(subMap + (next._2 -> next._2.subIds.length)) { case (sub, _) =>
    val subIds = sub.subIds ++ next._2.subIds
    (subMap - sub) + (sub.copy(subIds = subIds) -> subIds.length)
  })
}
```

I noticed that `count` is not used while folding and can be calculated using storeIds. Also, as `storeIds` can vary, the inner `Map` is rather useless as you will have to use `find` instead of `get` to fetch values from `Map`. So if you have control over your ADTs, you could use an intermediary ADT like:

```
case class SubscriptionStateWithoutIds(channel: Channel, state: ChannelState)
```

then you can rewrite your `foldLeft` as follows:

```
list.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, Map[SubscriptionStateWithoutIds, Seq[Long]]]) { (acc, next) =>
  val subMap = acc.getOrElse(next._1, Map.empty[SubscriptionStateWithoutIds, Seq[Long]])
  val withoutId = SubscriptionStateWithoutIds(next._2.channel, next._2.state)
  val channelSub = subMap.get(withoutId)
  acc + (next._1 -> (subMap + channelSub.fold(withoutId -> next._2.subIds) { seq => withoutId -> (seq ++ next._2.subIds) }))
}
```

The biggest advantage of intermediary ADT is you can have a cleaner `groupMapReduce` version:

```
list.groupMap(_._1)(sub => SubscriptionStateWithoutIds(sub._2.channel, sub._2.state) -> sub._2.subIds)
  .map { case (key, value) => key -> value.groupMapReduce(_._1)(_._2)(_ ++ _) }
```